# what are the ways to integrate a third party application with Jira?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jira

**what are the ways to integrate a third party application with Jira?**

I want to integrate **AWS** and **statuscake** third party apps with jira.
So any suggestion for How can i integrate it.

I need help about this.